The significance of "disciples AND Peter" in Mark 16:7
At the end of the Gospel of Mark, the boy in the tomb tells the women to give a message to "[Jesus's] disciples AND Peter" (Mark 16:7).
Nowhere else in Mark is any apostle "separated" from the word "disciples" and Peter, the "leader" of the disciples, is given second billing. What, if any, are the official church explanations for this unusual language?

Peter had denied the Lord three times, before the cock crowed. Thus the Lord singles him out especially, to confirm that he is, despite his denial, still included in the company 'disciples'.

Or perhaps he is excluded from the disciples? Is there clarification from a church authority?

Peter had denied the Lord three times, before the cock crowed. Thus the Lord singles him out especially, to confirm that he is, despite his denial, still included in the company 'disciples'.
I think this is fairly obvious and I suggest that  multiple churches will have noticed this but I cannot say whom they might be.

Excellent.  Jesus had Peter's restoration in mind even before the denials (Luke 22:31-32). +1

If Peter were stilll included, would Mark not have written (something that translates to) “the disciples including Peter”, or “the disciples, especially Peter”, or similar?

It's possible you're misinterpreting the word "disciples." Consider Luke 6:13 (KJV):

And when it was day, he called unto him his disciples: and of them he chose twelve, whom also he named apostles...

In other words, there was a group of more than twelve people who were labeled "disciples," and from that group twelve were chosen and called "apostles." Looked at from this perspective, Mary and Mary may have been invited to speak to two separate groups of people: the apostles through Peter, and the whole congregation (the disciples).
A poor support for this idea is Mark 2:18:

Why do the disciples of John and of the Pharisees fast, but thy disciples fast not?

The disciples of John, who certainly numbered more than twelve, versus the disciples of Jesus... who also numbered more than twelve (remember that verse in Luke). And while it would take a better analysis of other scripture than I'm prepared to offer this evening, most other verses using the word "disciples" in the book of Mark could be interpreted both ways: referring only to the smaller group of apostles or more generally to a group of more than twelve that included believers because there has always been a distinction between the crowd that had gathered to hear Jesus speak and the growing group of people who followed Him.
Looking further, and as it turns out, there is one pair of verses in Mark that use both the word "disciples" and the word "apostles." Mark 6:29-30:

And when his disciples heard of it, they came and took up his corpse, and laid it in a tomb. And the apostles gathered themselves together unto Jesus, and told him all things, both what they had done, and what they had taught.

I'm not an expert, but I suspect that Mark wanted the reader to know that it wasn't the apostles (or not just the apostles), but either a second group of believers in Christ (disciples) or a larger group than just the apostles who took the body of John the Baptist (Mark 6:29). The Apostles then told Jesus (Mark 6:30).
The two examples cited suggest that Mark wasn't worried bout the distinction between the larger group of followers, the disciples, and a specific group of disciples, the apostles, save in the one case when it really had to matter.
I regret that this isn't definitive. However, my conclusion is that a better interpretation of the story in Mark 16:7 might be, "go and testify of what you've heard to the believers... but go tell Peter first." And I believe this because you're right... it doesn't make sense to be only speaking of the apostles and yet to single Peter out.

As @JBH's answer shows, in the Gospel of Mark, "apostles" is a subset of "disciples", cf

Mark 3:14 where Jesus appointed the twelve (when the word "disciple" was just used in Mark 3:9 in the preceding pericope Mark 3:7-12 to refer to the larger group).  I'm not sure whether in Mark 3:13 "they came to him" refer to just the twelve or a larger number of disciples.  The 1986 Anchor Yale commentary by C.S. Mann said:

... The implication of this verse is plainly that a larger number of people was present from whom Jesus chose the Twelve.  Luke's version has it that this choice was preceded by a vigil of prayer in the hills.


Mark 6:30: the only other time "apostles" is used in Mark.


@NigelJ's interpretation that Peter is singled out in Mark 16:7 as referring to Peter's denial is also affirmed in the Anchor Yale commentary:

In both Matthew and Mark, though more strongly in the latter, the announcement of the resurrection is cut short with now go and say ...  It is likely that the emphasis on and to Peter may have the story of Peter's denial in mind.  Again the vocabulary is commonplace in Matthew and Mark: go (cf. Mark 1:44); his disciples (cf. Mark 2:15); Peter (cf. Mark 3:16).  Cf. also Acts 1:14, "with the women and Mary"; 1 Cor 15:5, "Kephas, one of the Twelve."  ...

Conclusion

Nowhere else in Mark is any apostle "separated" from the word "disciples" ...

This is not true (see Mark 3:14 and the commentary quotation above).

and Peter, the "leader" of the disciples, is given second billing.

This is not that strange (see commentary quotation above on other verses with similar language).  It is very plausible to interpret "disciples and Peter" to emphasize that the news was to be announced to the LARGER community of disciples, which is inclusive of the 12 apostles, with special mention of Peter not only as the leader of the twelve, but to show that Peter has been forgiven of his betrayal.

The Rock, JesusIt has been noted that Peter needed specially correction and forgiveness because he "denied the Lord" thrice. Just as a mother might say to a child who has misbehaved, Just wait until your father gets home!, so Peter's knowledge that Jesus is alive could have been quite upsetting to Peter.
He was guilty of abandonment at a crucial time of Jesus life. And knowing Jesus was alive may have been accepted as a threat that Jesus was gunning for him! Jesus was going to "read him the riot act"...going to "rack him over the coals"!
Peter needed grace, mercy...and forgiveness. Jesus was saying, "Peter, we have to talk. There's something about this crucifixion you need to understand. It's call mercy...salvation from the burden of guilt!"
The Stone, PeterRecall the experience at Caesarea Philippi, when Jesus explained to the disciples how He was to build His Church. Peter's confession was important then...and Jesus had to reassure Peter now that his statements back then were not misplaced. The Church would be built...and Peter was to have a large place in instituting it...still. (See the last chapter of John.) Rash statements in order to preserve his life did not disqualify Peter from his part in the Church. Peter had to know that...thus, "Tell Peter I want to see him."
In the second chapter of Acts we see from Peter's sermon that he did in fact learn the way of salvation....the way to freedom from guilt. An this, he declared to the multitudes. He was speaking from experience!
Later, when the Two Disciples returned from Emmaeus and met with the Apostles, they reported to them, "Peter has seen Jesus, too!" That was a loaded statement.
